# MS Word letterhead (page-header) with different margins on pages

Tags: header, ms-word

I have got a word document with two pages. The margin of the page-header should be different on the two pages. I tried a lot to have a margin of 4 cm on the first page and 9 cm on the second page but with no success. I used Word 2003.

What I did:

- Went to the second page and opened the "header and footer" bar.
- I added the page-numbers and top-margins and clicked on "page setup" on the "header and footer"-bar
- Afterwards I checked the box "different first page" and modified the header for the first page, too.

Problem:
THE MARGIN OF PAGE-HEADER IS THE SAME ON BOTH PAGES

Additional Info:
Actually I found this tutorial but it did not help me:

http://wordfaqs.mvps.org/Letterhead.htm

Answer (score 2):

It's easy if you know it:

Enter the header on the second page. Add as many "returns" as you need to widen the header to the bottom. Sometime the "returns" in the header have a delay. Finally click on "different first page". That's it! Now you have a different margin on the first page compared to the following pages.

It is confusing that word has an Option for the header-margin. This option changes the header only globally.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to break the links between two pages for the header section. Follow the following step:

1. Create the doc and click the Page Layout tab.
2. In the Page Setup group, choose the appropriate section break option from the Breaks dropdown.
3. In Word 2003, choose Break from the Insert menu. Choose a break from the resulting dialog and click OK.
4. Double-click in the new section's header space. In the context Design tab, click the Link To Previous option in the Navigation group. Here you may found the the link is disabled. This is because of you have not selected the appropriate break. Try with different section break.
5. In Word 2003, choose Header and Footer from the View menu to open the header in edit mode.
6. Click the Link To Previous button in the Header and Footer toolbar to break the link.
7. Now the links has been broken. You can change you header and footer to desired height/width.

I have checked this from [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/msoffice/accommodate-different-headers-and-footers-in-a-word-document/) and found working fine in office 2007 as well.